# Why integration?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, integration, inductance

[image]

This is the expression of an energy stored in an inductor, i know it came from integrating inductance (as a constant) and current with respect to time, but my question is why it was integrated? What is the relationship between energy and integration.

Comment: You should include the integral you are talking about so we are all on the same page

Comment: You should also specify more of what you are asking in the title instead of something ambiguous like "why integration" - perhaps "why integration for energy stored in inductor?"

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that you're talking about the following derivation.

We define the (instantaneous) back EMF of an inductor as follows -

$$ \epsilon_{L} (t) = - L \frac{\mathrm{d}I(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} $$

The instantaneous power delivered **by** the inductor would then be $P_{L, out}(t) = \epsilon_L(t) I(t)$, or, equivalently, the power delivered **to** the inductor would then be $P_{L, in} (t) = - \epsilon_{L}(t) I(t)$. We substitute the expression for the back EMF of the inductor in the expression for power delivered **to** the inductor to observe that -

$$ P_{L, in} (t) = L I(t) \frac{\mathrm{d}I(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{2} L \frac{\mathrm{d}I(t)^2}{dt}$$

The energy delivered to the inductor in some time interval $[t_0, t]$ then follows from the definition of power as being $P_{L, in} (t) = \frac{\mathrm{d}U_{L}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ -

$$ U(t) - U_(t_0) = \int_{t}^{t_0} P_{L, in} (t') \mathrm{d}t'$$

$$ \Rightarrow U(t) - U(t_0) = \frac{1}{2} L \int_{t_0}^{t} \frac{\mathrm{d}I(t')^2}{dt'} \mathrm{d}t' = \int_{t_0}^{t} \mathrm{d} I(t')^2$$

If we let $I(t_0) = I_0$ and $I(t) = I$, then we can recast our expression -

$$ U(I) - U(I_0) = \frac{1}{2} L \int_{I_0}^{I} \mathrm{d} I'^2 = \frac{1}{2} L (I^2 - I_0^2)$$

Now, it makes sense (but is in fact completely arbitrary) to choose $I_0 = 0$ and define $U(0) = 0$ (since intuitively, in the absence of current, the inductor doesn't **do** anything, and therefore cannot have stored energy), in which case we obtain -

$$ U(I) = \frac{1}{2} L I^2 $$

So, to answer your question, the integral comes in from the differential relationship between power and energy. Our definitions of inductance are more naturally stated to give us power, and we integrate to find change in energy, and like any other potential energy problem, we choose a convenient reference to actually "define" the energy of the inductor to be the stated expression.